# Get Phonebook contacts Detail page from custom list android

Tags: android, contacts

I have made a custom list in which I am getting all the phone book contacts and showing them in my own list with a custom view. I save all the contacts (inculding the contacts id) in an arraylist. When I click on a list I want it open all the details of that contact in the default android manner. Please can some one tell me if this is possible or not.

my code is below for saving the contacts in my own list:

```
arraylist = new ArrayList<PhoneBookUserEntity>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {

            PhoneBookUserEntity user = new PhoneBookUserEntity();
            // Pick out the ID, and the Display name of the
            // contact from the current row of the cursor
            user.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
            user.setPhoneBookName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
            //    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ user.getId(), null, null); 
            while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                user.sePhoneNumber(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));                 
            } 
            phones.close(); 
            //}
            // user.sePhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))); 

            Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + user.getId(), null, null); 
            while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
                // This would allow you get several email addresses 
                user.setEmailAddress(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))); 
            } 
            emails.close(); 
            user.setImageURI(getPhotoUri(user.getId()));
            arraylist.add(user);
            // Do something with the values you have,
            // such as print them out or add to a list
            //System.out.println("Current contact on this iteration is : " + name);

            // This is where we query for Emails, Addresses etc
            // Add snippets below into here, depending on what you need
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: BTW you can use the contacts picker to do similar functionality. Check out http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/how-to-call-android-contacts-list.html

Comment: I have the contacts in my custom list. I want to open the default view when some one clicks on a contact and they are shown the contacts details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This should open the contacts card in android

Comment: you will get androidruntimeexception:
"Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"


to fix it, insert:
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);